# How to get matplotlib to redraw axis

Tags: python, user-interface, numpy, matplotlib, tkinter

Here is the program I've been working on for a while, and I've gotten some good troubleshooting tips on here already.

It runs just fine, and speed is not of primary concerns because it's just supposed to give an intuitive look at how different graphs change with a varying input. But, how can I get the graphs to REDRAW completely, not just the line (it replots each axis on top of the old one without clearing it so it stacks up and becomes bogged down quickly).

Thanks all!

```
#!/usr/apps/Python/bin/python
import matplotlib, sys
matplotlib.use('TkAgg')
from numpy import arange, sin, pi
from matplotlib.backends.backend_tkagg import FigureCanvasTkAgg, NavigationToolbar2TkAgg
from matplotlib.figure import Figure
from Tkinter import *
import math
from matplotlib import pylab
import scipy
from scipy.stats import norm


master = Tk()
master.title("DePaul University Interactive Options Graphs")

pricePlot = Figure(figsize=(4,3), dpi=100, frameon=False)
a = pricePlot.add_subplot(111)
a.set_title('The Greeks')
priceDataPlot = FigureCanvasTkAgg(pricePlot, master=master)
priceDataPlot.get_tk_widget().grid(column=1, columnspan=2, row=1, rowspan=2)

vegaPlot = Figure(figsize=(4,3.5), dpi=75, frameon=False)
b = vegaPlot.add_subplot(1,1,1)
b.set_title('Vega')
vegaDataPlot = FigureCanvasTkAgg(vegaPlot, master=master)
vegaDataPlot.get_tk_widget().grid(row=2)

deltaPlot = Figure(figsize=(4,3.5), dpi=75, frameon=False)
c = deltaPlot.add_subplot(111)
c.set_title('Delta')
deltaDataPlot = FigureCanvasTkAgg(deltaPlot, master=master)
deltaDataPlot.get_tk_widget().grid(row=0,rowspan=2)

gammaPlot = Figure(figsize=(4,3.5), dpi=75, frameon=False)
d = gammaPlot.add_subplot(111)
d.set_title('Gamma')
gammaDataPlot = FigureCanvasTkAgg(gammaPlot, master=master)
gammaDataPlot.get_tk_widget().grid(column=3,row=2)

rhoPlot = Figure(figsize=(4,3.5), dpi=75, frameon=False)
e = rhoPlot.add_subplot(111)
e.set_title('Rho')
rhoDataPlot = FigureCanvasTkAgg(rhoPlot, master=master)
rhoDataPlot.get_tk_widget().grid(column=3,row=3)

thetaPlot = Figure(figsize=(4,3.5), dpi=75, frameon=False)
f = thetaPlot.add_subplot(111)
f.set_title('Theta')
thetaDataPlot = FigureCanvasTkAgg(thetaPlot, master=master)
thetaDataPlot.get_tk_widget().grid(column=3,row=0,rowspan=2)

a3Plot = Figure(figsize=(4,3.5), dpi=75, frameon=False)
g = a3Plot.add_subplot(111)
g.set_title('Price')
a3DataPlot = FigureCanvasTkAgg(a3Plot, master=master)
a3DataPlot.get_tk_widget().grid(row=3)


CallPutFlag='c'

def changePut():
    CallPutFlag='p'
    print CallPutFlag

def changeCall():
    CallPutFlag='c'
    print CallPutFlag


def main():

    T=250                                 # This will 
    timeSpread = range(T-200,T+200,20)    # all be user
                                          # inputted
                                          # values through
                                          # Tkinter GUI
                                          # 
                                          # JV 7/27/2012

    r=float(interestRate.get())
    S=float(stockPrice.get())
    K=float(strikePrice.get())
    v=float(volatility.get())




    def BlackScholes(t):

            d1 = (math.log(S/K)+(r+v*v/2.)*(float(t)/365))/(v*math.sqrt((float(t)/365)))
            d2 = d1-v*math.sqrt((float(t)/365))

            if CallPutFlag=='c':

                    return S*scipy.stats.norm.cdf(d1)-K*math.exp(-r*float(t))*scipy.stats.norm.cdf(d2)

            else:

                    return K*math.exp(-r*float(t))*scipy.stats.norm.cdf(-d2)-S*scipy.stats.norm.cdf(-d1)


    def delta(t):

            d1 = (math.log(S/K)+(r+v*v/2.)*(float(t)/365))/(v*math.sqrt((float(t)/365)))
            d2 = d1-v*math.sqrt((float(t)/365))

            if CallPutFlag=='c':
                    callDelta = scipy.stats.norm.cdf(d1)

                    return callDelta

            else:
                    putDelta = -scipy.stats.norm.cdf(-d1)

                    return putDelta

    def gamma(t):

            d1 = (math.log(S/K)+(r+v*v/2.)*(float(t)/365))/(v*math.sqrt((float(t)/365)))
            d2 = d1-v*math.sqrt((float(t)/365))
            gamma = scipy.stats.norm.pdf(d1)/(S*v*math.sqrt(float(t)))

            return gamma

    def rho(t):
            d1 = (math.log(S/K)+(r+v*v/2.)*(float(t)/365))/(v*math.sqrt((float(t)/365)))
            d2 = d1-v*math.sqrt((float(t)/365))

            if CallPutFlag=='c':
                    callRho = (K*t*scipy.stats.norm.cdf(d2)/100)*math.e**-(r*t)

                    return callRho

            else:
                    putRho = (-K*t*scipy.stats.norm.cdf(-d2)/100)*math.e**-(r*t)

                    return putRho

    def vega(t):
            d1 = (math.log(S/K)+(r+v*v/2.)*(float(t)/365))/(v*math.sqrt((float(t)/365)))

            return S*scipy.stats.norm.pdf(d1)*math.sqrt(float(t))/100

    def theta(t):

        d1 = (math.log(S/K)+(r+v*v/2.)*(float(t)/365))/(v*math.sqrt((float(t)/365)))
        d2 = d1-v*math.sqrt((float(t)/365))
        b = math.e**-(r*t)

        if CallPutFlag=='c':

                callTheta = -S*scipy.stats.norm.pdf(d1)*v/(2*math.sqrt(float(t))-r*K*b*scipy.stats.norm.cdf(d2))

                return callTheta

        else:
                putTheta = -S*scipy.stats.norm.pdf(d1)*v/(2*math.sqrt(float(t))+r*K*b*scipy.stats.norm.cdf(-d2))

                return putTheta


    tprices = [BlackScholes(i) for i in timeSpread]
    tdeltas = [delta(i) for i in timeSpread]
    tgammas = [gamma(i) for i in timeSpread]
    trhos = [rho(i) for i in timeSpread]
    tvegas = [vega(i) for i in timeSpread]
    tthetas = [theta(i) for i in timeSpread]

    a.cla()
    a.plot(timeSpread,tdeltas,'g-')
    a.plot(timeSpread,tgammas,'b-')
    a.plot(timeSpread,trhos,'m-')
    a.plot(timeSpread,tvegas,'r-')
    a.plot(timeSpread,tthetas,'c-')
    priceDataPlot.show()

    line, = b.plot(timeSpread,tvegas,'r-')
    vegaDataPlot.show()
    line.remove()

    line, = c.plot(timeSpread,tdeltas,'g-')
    deltaDataPlot.show()
    line.remove()

    line, = d.plot(timeSpread,tgammas,'b-')
    gammaDataPlot.show()
    line.remove()

    line, = e.plot(timeSpread,trhos,'m-')
    rhoDataPlot.show()
    line.remove()

    line, = f.plot(timeSpread,tthetas,'c-')
    thetaDataPlot.show()
    line.remove()

    line, = g.plot(timeSpread,tprices,'k-')
    a3DataPlot.show()
    line.remove()


##photo=PhotoImage(file='/Users/jaredvacanti/Desktop/Depaul.gif')
##Label(master, image=photo).grid()

w = Label(master, text="DePaul University Department of Finance \nInteractive Options Graphs")
w.grid(row=0,column=1,columnspan=2,pady=100)

r1 = Radiobutton(master, variable=CallPutFlag, value='c', text="Call",command=lambda root=master:main())
r2 = Radiobutton(master, variable=CallPutFlag, value='p', text="Put",command=lambda root=master:main())
r1.grid(row=0,column=1,columnspan=2,pady=50, sticky=N)
r2.grid(row=0,column=1,columnspan=1,pady=50, sticky=N)


interestRate = Scale(master, from_=0, to=5,orient=HORIZONTAL,label='Interest Rate', command=lambda root=master:main())
interestRate.set(1)
interestRate.grid(row=3,column=2)
stockPrice = Scale(master, from_=0, to=100,orient=HORIZONTAL,label='Stock Price', command=lambda root=master:main())
stockPrice.set(10.0)
stockPrice.grid(row=3,column=1,pady=10)
strikePrice = Scale(master, from_=0, to=100,orient=HORIZONTAL,label='Strike Price', command=lambda root=master:main())
strikePrice.set (11.0)
strikePrice.grid(row=3,rowspan=2,column=1,sticky=N)
volatility = Scale(master, from_=0, to=10,orient=HORIZONTAL,label='Volatility', command=lambda root=master:main())
volatility.set(1)
volatility.grid(row=3,rowspan=2,column=2,sticky=N)


def quit(master):
    master.destroy()

Button(master, borderwidth=0, bg='gray', text="Quit", command=lambda root=master:quit(master)).grid(row=3,rowspan=2,column=2,sticky=S,pady=30)
Button(master, borderwidth=0, bg='gray', text="Calculate").grid(row=3,rowspan=2, column=1,columnspan=1,sticky=S,pady=30)


main()
master.mainloop()
```

Comment: Would you mind stripping things down to a more succinct example?  As a more direct answer, what's happening is that you're adding a new line each time instead of updating the existing line's data.  Try using `line.set_data(...)` instead of calling `plot` each time.

Answer (score 1):

Remove `frameon=False` when create the Figure object:

```
Figure(figsize=(4,3), dpi=100)
```

If you want the background color of Figure is the same as Tk window, you can set it by `facecolor` aurgument:

```
Figure(figsize=(4,3), dpi=100, facecolor=TK_BACKGROUND_COLOR)
```

On my system:

```
TK_BACKGROUND_COLOR = (212.0/256,208.0/256,200.0/256)
```